# windows form text box text alignment

Tags: winforms, textbox

I have a windows form textbox and a browse button.
when i clicks the browse button  a folder selection dialog pops up and iam able to select a folder which will be shown in the text box

suppose my full folder path is "A:/somefolder/subfolder1/subfolder2"

My text box content is like

[image]

But i want my text box to look like

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how text boxes are internally designed but as a workaround you could do this:

```
if(folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    textbox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
    textbox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1); // puts the cursor at end of textbox
}
```